# How do I mount 2 Top level subvolumes on the same BTRFS partition when I have already installed home to a BTRFS disk during installation

Tags: 22.04, btrfs

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my machine. I used a RAID 6 volume as my home partition (36 TB).  The whole disk is only one partition /dev/sda1 formatted BTRFS mount to /home.
I wanted to create another top level (5) subvolume on this partition (/dev/sda1), and this is easily done if you boot into the install media and mount the BTRFS disk separately (mount to /media/ubuntu/UUID). You will see the @home subvolume this way, so I created another top level subvolume @images for virtual machine images.
The reason for doing this is 2 fold:

1. The RAID is the only volume with any appreciable space on my system.  The /boot (dev/sdb1) and / (/dev/sdb2) are on an ETX4 SATADOM of only 256GB, so the /home directory is located on the RAID volume (/dev/sda1).
2. I wanted the images and home subvolumes separate for backup purposes.  I did not want the images subvolume to be a child of the home directory because I did not want to backup virtual machine images when I backed up my home directory.

Initially I created my fstab in the following way:

> UUID=4d0792cb-339f-4266-8cef-03afc51a3ce9 /                             ext4      errors=remount-ro             0       1  #ROOT DIRECTORY

> UUID=6462-E921           /boot/efi                     vfat    umask=0077    0       1 # BOOT DIRECTORY

> UUID=7779a2d8-23e2-4c81-8db8-677f57a2bacc /home                         btrfs   defaults,subvol=@home         0       2 #HOME DIRECTORY

> UUID=7779a2d8-23e2-4c81-8db8-677f57a2bacc /var/lib/libvirt/images       btrfs   defaults,subvol=@images       0       2  #IMAGES DIRECTORY

I thought that since these were 2 top level subvolumes on the same partition, there would be no problem since they were specified in fstab.  I WAS WRONG.  The system would hang on boot.

The reason I suspect is this: The /home directory located in @home would be mounted first, so it could not find the @images subvolume.  I have read that you need 2 separate partitions each with a Top Level subvolume, but I was lazy and did not want to create 2 partitions, and I did not know how large my @ images subvolume would need since I would be adding virtual machines as my needs increased.  I wanted BOTH subvolumes (@home @images) on the SAME partition (/dev/sda1).  How does one go about doing this?  The answer is coming up.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple.  When you list subvolumes using the following command:

```
btrfs subvolume list /media/ubuntu/UUID  (UUID is the identifier of the BTRFS partition)
```

it lists all the subvolumes on that partition complete with its ***subvolume ID***

Use this ***subvolume ID*** in fstab to mount the subvolume

```
UUID=7779a2d8-23e2-4c81-8db8-677f57a2bacc /home                         btrfs   defaults,subvol=@home         0       2
UUID=7779a2d8-23e2-4c81-8db8-677f57a2bacc /var/lib/libvirt/images       btrfs   defaults,subvolid=257        0       2
```

here ***subvolid=257*** is used instead of ***subvol=@images***

Problem solved.